# Display modal directly on page load without using button with materialize css

Tags: materialize

I want to load materialize modal without using button on page load. How to do that? Please help.

Answer (score 2):

This will open a modal on page load. Just put it inside the document.ready function.

```
$('#modal1').openModal();
```

Be sure to replace '#modal1' with the id of the modal that you want to open.

Comment: The way you use modals in Materialize has changed a lot in the last 2 years. The latest info is available here: [http://materializecss.com/modals.html](http://materializecss.com/modals.html)